# Workload installation failed: No space left on device when clearly there is

Tags: c#, .net, linux, maui, maui-android

When I'm executing command

```
sudo dotnet workload install maui-android --temp-dir $(HOME)/.temp
```

It installs packages, but at the end it outputs:

```
Workload installation failed: No space left on device
```

df -h ~/.temp output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3  476G   35G  441G   8% /home
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you specified a path for the temp-dir, that doesn't mean that's the only place it needs to store files

Comment: @Jason How can I specify all the directories for it then? or at least log all the directories that is in use by the dotnet's installation?

Comment: I’m sure there are flags to set the verbosity level of messages

Comment: There is an issue about [Workload installation failed: No space left on device](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/28962). Can it help you?